# What is the southernmost border crossing from Thailand to Myanmar that's open to foreigners?

Tags: international-travel, borders, thailand, myanmar

There's a range of land border crossings between Thailand and Myanmar, but I'm having trouble finding solid info on them to choose which one to use.

I'll be coming from Krabi, so I want the closest border crossing. I don't care about which is most popular, easiest, etc. I just want the closest one, which means the one furthest to the south.

But one other thing is important. There are usually border crossings open only to locals, citizens of the countries either side of the border. And of course there are crossings open to everybody, including foreigners.

As a bonus, it used to be that there was a range of restrictions at some border crossings in Myanmar, such as that you had to return to Thailand via the same crossing, or that you weren't permitted to travel from there to arbitrary places in the country. I don't know if this is still the case but if it is, I'd like the crossing with the fewest restrictions.

Comment: [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myanmar) says that four border Thailand-Myanmar crossings are open to foreigners, including the river crossing at Kawthaung.  Can't get more southern than that.  However, Wikivoyage is silent on whether you must exit Myanmar at the same location.

Comment: Aha that's much further south than I managed to find even though I did have a look at Wikivoyage. It seems eVisas can be used there, which turned out to be an issue at some other crossings.

Answer (score 3):

On my last trip to Myanmar in 2016, I entered by foot at Mae Sot and left by boat from Kawthoung to Ranong Thailand, this is the most southern crossing and walking distance to the main road from Krabi.

So entering and leaving at different crossings was no problem.
It was possible to enter in Kawthoung. I didn't have an eVisa so I don't know about that.

The road up north from Kawthoung was open for walking and hitch hiking, but there were also buses.

I don't have up to date information but I don't expect the rules in this part of the country have changed.